# Avoid user to go ../../

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have LAMP installed in my server and I use virtualhosts to map domains to subdirectories. I need to allow my customers to upload files (including php) to their server using FTP.

The problem is that a customer using a domain xxx.com.br uploaded a file test.php and executed it like:

xxx.com.br/test.php

The content of test.php if file_put_contents("../../xxx.txt","teste") and it worked! The file xxx.txt was created 2 levels above his domain folder! How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are these individual apache virtual hosts?

Comment: You could likely use something like [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) to restrict the user to just their folder. However, if you allow htaccess files, it can be overridden.

Comment: You're allowing uses to upload arbitrary files and you're putting them into your site's document root? Good luck **NOT** getting your server utterly destroyed...

Comment: I believe OP is trying to create their own shared hosting system. Not just allowing arbitrary users to upload files.

Comment: are you sure that open_basedir  can be overriden by htaccess? so can I  do that in a shared envirorment? I want not to allow users to go above their home dir but I need to allow them to use htaccess!

Answer (score 2):

Don't give the PHP process access to directories it isn't meant to reach.

That's kind of the point of the whole permission system.

In Linux, PHP will generally run as its own user, just make sure that user doesn't have read or write permission to any files you don't want exposed.

Comment: this will secure the server, but it won't prevent the users (assuming multiple customers) to access each other's content.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Normally this is "secured" by choosing higly randomized, hard to guess paths to web roots. More secure would be using PHP as (F)CGI executable. It can be configured in a way that it runs as the user who owns the document root. Then the admin must make sure, that the user has no file access except from it's document root (and `/tmp` on most systems)

Comment: I'm glad you've put the word "secured" in quotes... ;)

Comment: You could improve the answer by telling what should he actually use.

Comment: @Yoda and any other contributor, feel free to edit this answer to improve it with good practices. I will approve any constructive edit.

Comment: After some help here and after googling all this day I discovered I just need to add this one line to my vhosts file: 

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /vol/public_html/xxx.com.br
    php_admin_value open_basedir /vol/public_html/xxx.com.br
    ...
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: @amandanovaes Correct, I suggested using `open_basedir` in my answer. Moreover it would be beneficial for you to use `FastCGI`.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose exists `open_basedir` configuration directive. More information about it for example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).

Moreover it is good to use `FastCGI` which allows each script to be run under its owner. More information about it for example [here](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/).